# how do I set the column width on phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

My tables have fulltext columns . How do I set the default width of the columns? I know it has the full/partial text buttons at the top of the index.php page...how do I set that value permanently?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a config value called LimitChars: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#LimitChars

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I edited the config.inc.php and config.default.php (even though it says not to) but neither worked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You have to set this in config.inc.php. It works for me. Which value did you assign?

Comment: I tried many different values....5, 12, 500, 85, etc....do you have to restart anything?

Comment: Which phpmyadmin version are you using?

Comment: Note: if you don't want to increase the limit permanently (I'm speaking not to the OP, but to others like me who came here just looking for a **way to temporarily increase the limit**) the updated link that @D.Tate provided says (about the character limit config value) => "Maximum number of characters shown in any non-numeric field on browse view. **Can be turned off by a toggle button on the browse page.**" This "toggle button" is found in the  **+Options tab just above the query results**.